# gdal_calc.py returns "The system cannot find the path specified." with Anaconda3

Tags: python, anaconda, gdal

when I run the following command:

```
python gdal_calc.py -A "C:\Users\Username\GDAL\Python\unwrappedPhase\20190118_20190106.vrt" -B "C:\Users\Username\GDAL\Python\connectedComponents\20190118_20190106.vrt" --outfile "C:\Users\Username\GDAL\Python\results\20190118_20190106_defo" --calc='((A*(B>0))/(4*pi)*5.546576)' --format=ENVI --NoDataValue=0 --overwrite
```

The Shell returns:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I'm using Anaconda3 on Win10 64bit.

Comment: Are you sure you got the path 100% correct?

Comment: yes I am. @PNX .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I fixed it. I only changed the quotation marks from ' to " and changed the `outfile` to only `defo` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the .vrt file. Execute

```
conda init
```

and restart the anaconda prompt. It should initialize the conda environment again.